# imagem do banner ficar do lado direito

Tags: css

Como eu faço para que a imagem fique no lado direito da div? Veja abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que estou tentando aqui é esse:

```
<div class="img img-responsive" style="background-color: #1F356A;" align="right"> 
   <div style="background-image: url('banner/banner.png'); height: 100px;  margin-top: -23px; line-height: 100px; color: #BCA828; font-family: Arial; font-size: 48px; text-align: center">
       HISTÓRIA
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tenta colocar `float: right`

Comment: Olá Francisco. Infelizmente não funcionou. O banner não aparece mais.

Comment: Recomendo utilizar o flexbox já é aceito por 95% dos navegadores..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer isso use a propriedade `background-position` com o valor `right`, segue exemplo:

```
seletor{
    background-position: right;
}
```

Como você quer posicionar o `background` do elemento, e não o elemento em si, o `float: right` não funciona!

Comment: Obrigado Lucas. Funcionou!

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o FlexBox para ajustar seus elementos com uma simplicidade incrível!

```
.sua-classe-pai {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end; // flex-start é o padrão // center centraliza...
}
```

Recomendo pesquisar mais sobre o assunto!